# Rspec invalid option-f OptionParser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, rspec, rvm

I recently started the "Intro to Rails" screencast on nettuts. So I am not very familiar with Rails obviously and only know a little about Ruby. Everything else in the code will run correctly however when I run guard-rspec it displays this:

```
/Users/hanssingh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1013:in `block in process_args': invalid option: -f (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    from /Users/hanssingh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:992:in `new'
    from /Users/hanssingh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:992:in `process_args'
    from /Users/hanssingh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1042:in `_run'
    from /Users/hanssingh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1035:in `run'
    from /Users/hanssingh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
    from /Users/hanssingh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:774:in `run'
    from /Users/hanssingh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:366:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
    from /Users/hanssingh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
    from /Users/hanssingh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:365:in `block in autorun'
```

I am not very sure what this error means and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Can you give the whole stack-trace, instead of just the top part of it?

Comment: From what you've posted, your running Minitest, not RSpec...

Comment: Could you add the command your using in your question ?

Comment: I too encountered this error after following the same screencast. I'm assuming you're using guard. Try instead running `rspec spec` in your project's root. This should avoid your problem.

If anyone could shed some light on why guard can't manage this that would be excellent. I think it's a decent tool.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be caused by the turn gem (I suspect you have it). Remove it from your Gemfile, run bundle again, and then try your tests with guard once more. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Was having a similar issue getting Test::Unit errors when running Guard:

```
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:49:in `process_args': invalid option: -f (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
```

According to https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/170 this was caused by having the shoulda gem included in my Gemfile. Changing this to should-matchers fixed the issue for me without having to lose the loveliness of shoulda.

Studying the Nettuts 'Intro to Rails' Gemfile it seems to contain the 'turn' gem which is minitest-based. So removing this from your Gemfile should help, as @kladd suggests.